# PHP variables not changing outside of function

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function in PHP. I am passing two arrays to the function as references. While the function updates `$array2` outside the function, it does not update `$array`. Below is my function.

```
function JobAssign($i,&$array,&$array2,$Machine_Interchange) {
    $compmachine = $array[$i]['Machine_Name'];
    $CLT = $array[$i]["Estimated_Start_Date"];
    $ET = $array[$i]["Estimated_Completion_Date"];

    $Machine = $array[$i]['Machine_Name'];
    $Compatibility_sql = "SELECT Machine2 FROM Machine_Interchange where Machine1 = '$Machine' and Value = 1";
    $compatibility_query = mysql_query($Compatibility_sql) or die(mysql_error());
    for($i=0; $compatibility[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($compatibility_query);$i++);
    array_pop($compatibility);  
    $maxkey = max(array_keys($compatibility));
    $maxnumber = max(array_keys($array2))+1;
    $k=0;
    do{
        $compmachine = $compatibility[$k]['Machine2'];
        $CLT = $array2[$compmachine];
        if($array2[$compatibility[$k]['Machine2']]>$array2[$compatibility[$k+1]['Machine2']]) {
            $compmachine = $compatibility[$k+1]['Machine2'];
            $CLT = $array2[$compatibility[$k+1]['Machine2']];                                           
        }
        $k=$k+1;    
    }

    while($k<$maxkey);                                                  
    $array[$i]["Machine_Name"] = $compmachine;
    $array[$i]["Estimated_Start_Date"] = $CLT;                    
    $prodhours = $array[$i]["Prod_Hrs"];
    $array[$i]["Estimated_Completion_Date"] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($CLT . " +$prodhours hour"));
    $array2[$compmachine] = $array[$i]["Estimated_Completion_Date"];

    echo $array[$i]['Machine_Name'].'<br>';
    echo $array[$i]['Estimated_Start_Date'].'<br>';
    echo $array[$i]['Estimated_Completion_Date'].'<br>';
    echo $array2[$compmachine].'<br>';
}

JobAssign(0,$Jobs_Data,$LT,$Machine_Interchange);

echo $Jobs_Data[0]['Machine_Name'].'<br>';
echo $Jobs_Data[0]['Estimated_Start_Date'].'<br>';
echo $Jobs_Data[0]['Estimated_Completion_Date'].'<br>';
echo $LT['Machine 3'];
```

Below is the output that I get.The first 4 lines of the output are from within the function and the next 4 are from outside the function.

```
Machine 3
2014-07-12 00:00:00
2014-07-15 11:00:00
2014-07-15 11:00:00
Machine 1
2014-07-30 00:00:00
2014-08-02 00:00:00
2014-07-15 11:00:00
```

When I echo the changed variables inside the function they do change but when I echo `$array`outside of the function it does not change the values for `$array`. Only the values for `$array2` have changed even though I have passed both arrays as reference in the function arguments. Which means that the line 4 and 8 are the same in the output which means that values for $array2 have changed but not for $array.

Comment: Where are you calling the `JobAssign` function?

Comment: I am calling the function after it has been defined and passing 2 different arrays for $array and $array2.

Comment: Please add the call to your question so that it can also be checked.

Comment: Use `print_r($array);` in various places to see the output.

Comment: When I echo the variables within the function, the changes have been made to both $array as well as $array2. But when I echo the variables outside the function for they key which is $i that I pass as an argument, the changes are only been made to the array I pass as $array2 but not to the array I pass as $array in the argument.

Comment: I just does not change anything in the '$array' array but just changes the '$array2' array. Is there anything in the function that may be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the variable $i on your for loop to another variable. Because it changes the value of the variable while it is looping.

```
function JobAssign($i,&$array,&$array2,$Machine_Interchange)
{

$compmachine = $array[$i]['Machine_Name'];
$CLT = $array[$i]["Estimated_Start_Date"];
$ET = $array[$i]["Estimated_Completion_Date"];

$Machine = $array[$i]['Machine_Name'];
        $Compatibility_sql = "SELECT Machine2 FROM Machine_Interchange where Machine1 = '$Machine' and Value = 1";
                    $compatibility_query = mysql_query($Compatibility_sql) or die(mysql_error());
                    for($ii=0; $compatibility[$ii] = mysql_fetch_assoc($compatibility_query);$ii++);
                        array_pop($compatibility);  
                          $maxkey = max(array_keys($compatibility));
                          $maxnumber = max(array_keys($array2))+1;
                                            $k=0;
                                            do{
                                                $compmachine = $compatibility[$k]['Machine2'];
                                                $CLT = $array2[$compmachine];   
                                            if($array2[$compatibility[$k]['Machine2']]>$array2[$compatibility[$k+1]['Machine2']])
                                                {
                                                    $compmachine = $compatibility[$k+1]['Machine2'];                        
                                                    $CLT = $array2[$compatibility[$k+1]['Machine2']];                                                                                                           
                                                }
                                                $k=$k+1;    
                                              }
                                            while($k<$maxkey);                                                                                                              
$array[$i]["Machine_Name"] = $compmachine;
$array[$i]["Estimated_Start_Date"] = $CLT;                    
$prodhours = $array[$i]["Prod_Hrs"];
$array[$i]["Estimated_Completion_Date"] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($CLT . " +$prodhours hour"));                             
$array2[$compmachine] = $array[$i]["Estimated_Completion_Date"];

echo $array[$i]['Machine_Name'].'<br>';
echo $array[$i]['Estimated_Start_Date'].'<br>';
echo $array[$i]['Estimated_Completion_Date'].'<br>';
echo $array2[$compmachine].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in line which is $array3 = $this->JobAssign($i,&$array,&$array2,$Machine_Interchange);

Comment: @SujayMahale sorry I putted `&` sign while calling the function

Comment: thank you for your help. It still does not work that way. Besides my whole plan is to use the function for each array key for '$array'. Every time I use it for a key, the '$array2' array is updated as an input for the next use of the function for the next key in '$array'. But why does it not update the variables in $array when I pass it as a reference in the function argument.

Comment: thank you for trying, it still does not update nor change anything. Is there anything in the function you can spot that could be changed to make this work?

Comment: @SujayMahale I didn't notice that you have used again the variable $i on your for loop. It results on changing the value of the $i variable while it was used in the for loop

Comment: That helped a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Silly mistakes are what are the worst. Lol. Thanks a lot Mr Lee.

Comment: @SujayMahale Just check one answer dude haha :D you can only accept one answer

Answer (score 0):

The `$array` is changed as it should, the problem is that is changed in the wrong index.

**Explanation:**

You call the function with `$i = 0` but `$i` is also used in the loop statement and exits the loop with a different value.

here is the line:

```
for($i=0; $compatibility[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($compatibility_query);$i++);
```

after the above `$i` is no longer `0` (as long as you have something to fetch)

So the index of `$array` that you echo inside the function is different from the index of `$array` you echo outside the function.

To fix your problem just change the variable of the above loop to something else, let's say `$j`:

```
for($j=0; $compatibility[$j] = mysql_fetch_assoc($compatibility_query);$j++);
```

so that no longer affects `$i`

Comment: That helped a lot. Silly mistake by me. Thank you so much. :-)